# Inject a p namespace attribute using spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean defined similar to below in my spring.xml. I am converting all my beans into annotation based. How can I inject the attributes in the below listed bean?

```
<bean
        id = "dataPropDao"
        class = "com.service.ref.DataPropDaoImpl"
        p:dataSource-ref = "data.dataSource"
        p:sql = "PROFILE_PKG.GetProfileByCode"
        p:function = "true"/>
```

Comment: From where do you intend to grab the sql property (String?) and function property (boolean?String?)?

Comment: @Mechkov , thanks for your response. It is an existing app and I am trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"p" namespace is used to set bean properties using setters. Equivalent of your code in Java config would be similar to:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    DataPropDaoImpl dataPropDao(DataSource datasource) {
        DataPropDaoImpl dao = new DataPropDaoImpl();
        dao.setDataSource(datasource);
        dao.setSql("PROFILE_PKG.GetProfileByCode");
        dao.setFunction(true);
        return dao;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I will try this. What is meant by "PROFILE_PKG.GetProfileByCode" in this case and where can I find  it?

Comment: It is a string value. I can't tell where you should look for it - it's specific to your project. If you don't find it anywhere in your source code perhaps it is a stored procedure on the database server?